# Creating a method for a Plinko game

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a Plinko game by having a method with three parameters called num, prevNum (which is our previous random number) and score (which is kept track of on a certain condition).

The Win condition is if the score is  greater than 100 than you print out something to the user and the score

The lose condition is if both num and prevNum are the same number, then print out something and num

There are also two conditions, if num is odd, add it to prevNum.
If num is even, multiply it by 2, add it to score and print out something to the user

if none of these if statements pass, then do a recursive call

I started off by creating the random number between 1-10

```
(defn ball [] (inc (rand-int 10)))
```

and i created the plinko method but it doesn't work

```
    (defn plinko [num prevNum score] (println "You got a " num) (if (= num prevNum) (println "You got double " num ". NO PLINKO!")
                                                                                (if (odd? num) (+ prevNum num)
                                                                                               (if (even? num) ((+ score (* 2 num)) (println "DOUBLE POINT BONUS!"))
                                                                                                               (if (> score 100) (println "PLINKO! Your total money was: $" score) (plinko num prevNum score))))))
```

I don't know how to connect the ball and plinko method nor do any of my past questions help me, i lack the knowledge to do this. I would really appreciate it if i could receive some help.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't" work?  What arguments did you call the function with, what was the expected value, and what did you get?

Comment: There seems to be some problem in your description.  num is either or odd or even.  So "If none of these if statements pass, ..." will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of the problem statement.

Create a function `plinko` with the parameters `num`, `prev-num`, and `score`.  If `num` and `prev-num` are equal, then you lose.  Otherwise, if `num` is odd, increment the `score` by `num`.  Otherwise, increment the `score` by twice the value of `num`.  If the updated score is greater than 100, then you win.  Otherwise call the `plinko` function recursively with updated values.

Assuming that is what you wanted, here is a definition of the function and two example calls.

```clj
user> (defn ball [] (inc (rand-int 10)))
#'user/ball
user> (defn plinko [num prev-num score]
        (println "You got a " num)
        (if (= num prev-num)
          (println "You got double " num ". NO PLINKO!")
          (let [new-score (if (odd? num)
                            (+ score num)
                            (do (println "DOUBLE POINT BONUS!")
                                (+ score (* 2 num))))]
            (if (> new-score 100)
              (println "PLINKO! Your total money was: $" new-score)
              (plinko (ball) num new-score)))))
#'user/plinko
user> (plinko (ball) nil 0)
You got a  8
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  9
You got a  5
You got a  3
You got a  3
You got double  3 . NO PLINKO!
nil
user> (plinko (ball) nil 0)
You got a  2
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  1
You got a  4
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  8
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  6
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  8
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  6
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  8
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
You got a  9
You got a  5
You got a  10
DOUBLE POINT BONUS!
PLINKO! Your total money was: $ 119
nil
user>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
(defn rand-num [max-num]
  (inc (rand-int max-num)))

(defn plinko [& {:keys [max-num score last-num] :or {max-num 10 score 0 last-num 0}}]
  (loop [num (rand-num max-num)
         score score
         prev last-num]
    (println "You got a " num ". Your score is " score ".")
    (cond 
      (> score 100) (println "PLINKO! Your total money was: $" score) 
      (even? num) (do (println "DOUBLE POINT BONUS!")
                          (recur (rand-num max-num)
                                 (+ score (* 2 num))
                                 num))
      (= num prev) (println "You got double " num ". NO PLINKO!")
      :else (recur (rand-num max-num)
                   score
                   num))))

(plinko :max-num 10 :score 0 :last-num 0)
```